# RxJs 6 load more pagination stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to build one of those more modern paginations where there's not dedicated links for the individual pages but one where more results are loaded automatically when the user scrolls to the bottom. On the web page are multiple widgets that allow you to modify the search parameters. When the parameters change more results should be fetched via ajax beginning from the first page again.
I'm fairly new to RxJs and I'm having issues wrapping my head arround how to identify the observables/subjects I need and how to compose them to achive the described behavior.

Here's the specific flow I have in mind:

When the page is first loaded an initial set of parameters is taken and used to load the first page. When a "load more" event is fired the next page should be fetched and rendered to the page.

When the parameters change the page should be loaded starting from page 1 again.

When the server signals that there are no more results to load I should get notified about that via an observable. If further "load more" events are fired after no more pages are available the ajax request should not be made to save bandwidth on mobile devices.

Lastly as long as a network request is open i want to be able to display a loader so i need an observable that informs me about whether there are open requests or not.

As a bonus: Currently I've implemented signaling no more results by returning a 404 from the backend when a page one bigger than last page is requested. I'd like to use `catchError` on the ajax observable in such a way, that it gracefully stops the ajax request without breaking the subscription.

Here's what I was able to come up with so far, but it has multiple Problems (described below):

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, fromEvent } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, mergeMap, switchMap, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { stringify } from 'qs';

const paramsEl = document.querySelector<HTMLTextAreaElement>('#params');
const paramsChangedBtn = document.querySelector<HTMLButtonElement>('#paramsSubmit');
const loadNextPageBtn = document.querySelector<HTMLButtonElement>('#loadNextPage');

const getParams = () => JSON.parse(paramsEl.value);

const params$ = new BehaviorSubject(getParams());
const page$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const noMoreResults$ = new Subject<void>();       // <- public
const connections$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);
const loading$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);      // <- public

// for the sake of this example we're not using an IntersectionObserver etc. but a plain button to fire a "load more" event
const loadNextPage$ = fromEvent(loadNextPageBtn, 'click');
// same for params changed event. In my real app I've got a working stream fed from the widgets
fromEvent(paramsChangedBtn, 'click').subscribe(e => params$.next(getParams()));

// when the params change, reset page to 1
params$.subscribe(() => page$.next(1));

// update loading$ observable for displaying/hiding a loader
connections$.subscribe(connections => {
  if(connections > 0 && loading$.getValue() === false) loading$.next(true);
  if(connections <= 0 && loading$.getValue() === true) loading$.next(false);
});

// when we need to load the next page, increment the page observable
loadNextPage$.subscribe(e => page$.next(page$.getValue() + 1));

//////////////

// whenever a new page should be requested, get the current parameters and fetch data for this page
page$
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(noMoreResults$),
    tap(() => connections$.next(connections$.getValue() + 1)),
    mergeMap(page => {
      const qs = stringify({
        ...params$.getValue(),
        page,
      });
      return ajax.getJSON<any>(`https://httpbin.org/get?${qs}`)
        // this doesn't seem to do anything
        // furthermore the ajax request would already have been made at this point
        // .pipe(
        //   takeUntil(noMoreResults$)
        // );
    }),
    tap(() => connections$.next(connections$.getValue() - 1)),
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.args);
    // for testing purposes pretend we have no more data at page 5
    if(data.args.page === "5") noMoreResults$.next();
  });

// for debugging purposes
loading$.subscribe(loading => console.log('loading: ', loading));
noMoreResults$.subscribe(() => console.warn('no more results'));
```

You can find the running version of this here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rcfsko-modern-pagination-attempt-3?file=index.ts).

Here's the issues with the code:

1. Current pace of `takeUntil(noMoreResults$)` breaks the subscription when `noMoreResults$` has been triggered and then `params$` emits no further pages are loaded. (See comment in the code for the other location in the ajax pipe).
2. using `params$.getValue()` when mergeMapping to the ajax observable feels wrong, however I don't know how to pass down both the page number as well as the parameters in one stream properly.
3. In general I think I've overused Subjects / BehaviorSubjects quite a bit but I'm not sure. Can you either confirm or deny this?
4. The composition of the observables feel very messy and hard to follow. Is this based on what I'm trying to do or is there room for improvement for this problem?

Can you please provide a working example as well as elaborating on the biggest mistakes I've made.

Comment: If you have access to Pluralsight, this talk by Aaron Frost https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-denver-2019-session-27 goes through setting up pagination with RxJS. It's not exactly like your example, but may provide some additional ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I have been keeping this question open in my tabs ever since you created this question, wanting to help, but also, wanting to learn enough of the RxJS so I could create a solution myself.

I'm really sorry, but I haven't looked at your example, but instead, I created my own. I would have to ask you to please forgive me for the extremely large answer that I will provide here.

I was mainly driven by the excellent talk by [Ben Lesh](https://github.com/benlesh), one of the creators of modern RxJS which you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-nFj2o03i8). I strongly suggest that you look at this video, even multiple times, to try to understand some of the stuff I used in my solution to this problem.

Like Ben, I also used Angular framework as the basis for this project. You can find my solution at [GitHub](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams). Also, just like Ben has been explaining couple of times in his talk some Angular specific stuff, I will try to do it here as well.

What I've got in my app are a simple [`FeedComponent`](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams/blob/master/src/app/feed-component/feed.component.ts) and a [`FeedService`](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams/blob/master/src/app/feed-service/feed.service.ts). The service is being injected using Angular Dependency Injection to the `FeedComponent`.

Now, I've got an HTML bound to `FeedComponent` [that looks like this](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams/blob/master/src/app/feed-component/feed.component.html):

```html
<div class="loading" *ngIf="loading$ | async">
  Loading...
</div>
<div class="filter">
  <form #form="ngForm">
    ...
  </form>
</div>
<div #articles class="articles">
  <article *ngFor="let article of feed$ | async">
    ...
  </article>
</div>
```

You can see that I've got three sections: a `<div>` responsible for displaying a message that the feed is being loaded; another `<div>` with filtering `<form>` that displays filtering options; and a third `<div>` responsible for displaying feed items as a list of `<article>`s.

Angular specific stuff here include `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` directives and `async` pipe (`|`). With a single sentence: `*ngIf` renders certain DOM element if condition stated in attribute value is truthy; `*ngFor` loops through an array of provided items and renders certain DOM element number of times of the array's length; pipe `|` transforms items so that items to the left are always input items to the pipe to the right, so does the `async` pipe do - it transforms an Observable (you can tell that it's an Observable by the `$` sign suffix that I and many others are using) to transform items that come from the Observable to what the directive understands. `async` pipe is also explained in Ben's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-nFj2o03i8&t=557).

Let's get started: you can see that I'm using two Observables in my HTML template, and that's all you need. The one that will give you an array of [`FeedItems`](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams/blob/master/src/app/models.ts#L12) so you can display them on the page, and the other one that will emit boolean values when feed is being fetched from server. If you would not use Angular, but rather some other framework or library, or nothing at all, you could still have only these two streams. You would have to manually subscribe to them (and unsubscribe later, when not needed anymore) and when you'd get results, you should update the DOM accordingly. Angular and `async` pipe do all of this here for me.

These two are `feed$` and `loading$` Observable streams, respectively. Both of them are defined in the `FeedComponent` that is bound to this HTML, very simply, like this:

```
feed$ = this.feedService.feed$;

loading$ = this.feedService.loading$.pipe(delay(10));
```

As I said, `feedService` is injected to `FeedComponent` through `FeedComponent`'s constructor using Angular DI:

```
constructor(private feedService: FeedService) {}
```

You would just have to create new `FeedService` object if you'd use your own JS framework/lib or no lib at all. I'm adding delay of 10 ms to `feedService.loading$` stream because I'm getting some Angular error that I should not explain here. You may not need it at all if not using Angular.

Now, to be able to provide feed items (`FeedItems[]`) through `feed$` stream, you need to listen to the two possible events: a scroll event that would fire when the user has scrolled enough to the bottom of the page and an event that happens when filter form input values change. These two events need to be combined to a single Observable that we will call `filterSeed$` - it will emit values contained in the input elements of the used `form`.

The first event stream can be formed out of these two Observables:

```
scrollPercent$: Observable<number> = fromEvent(document, 'scroll')
  .pipe(
    map(() => {
      const scrollTop = this.articles.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const docHeight = this.articles.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      const winHeight = window.innerHeight;
      const scroll = scrollTop / (winHeight - docHeight);

      return Math.round(scroll * 100);
    })
  );

loadMore$: Observable<number> = this.scrollPercent$
  .pipe(
    filter(percent => percent >= 80),
    take(1),
    repeatWhen(() => this.feedLoadingStops$)
  );
```

`scrollPercent$` is an Observable that emits some numbers. They represent scroll percentage when `document`'s `scroll` event fires (created using `fromEvent`). Whatever event it emits, I don't really care about it. I only care about *when* it emits, so I can `map` it to percentages using some simple math. `this.articles.nativeElement` is Angular specific, so if you need another example, please take a look at [this Pen](https://codepen.io/achudars/pen/Cpast) about how to achieve it with jQuery. The returning value of the `map` function is rounded scroll percentage.

`loadMore$` is an Observable that fires events only when a user has scrolled enough so that new feed items should be loaded - it fires scroll percentage number, but we don't really care about that, you'll see that we're ignoring these numbers later. The threshold when this should happen is at or after 80% of the scroll. So, I'm using `filter` here to let only those items that are above the threshold (remember, I need `loadMore$` to emit when this threshold is reached and passed). And I'm using `take(1)` here because I really only need one such item.

Just like Ben has [had a problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-nFj2o03i8&t=1824) when the whole stream only worked once, I was having it as well. Because `take` [completes](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/take#description) (effectively unsubscribes) from the source when it takes that one item, I need to resubscribe again to the same source, which is, all the way to the top, the stream created by `fromEvent`.

So, I need to start listening to the `scroll` events once again, but there's catch here: I don't want to start doing it immediately, but rather when the loading completes. So, I need to use `repeatWhen` instead of just `repeat`. `repeatWhen` takes a factory function that it calls when needed to get an Observable to subscribe to. It listens to the provided Observable (`this.feedLoadingStops$`) and resubscribes to the source when the `this.feedLoadingStops$` emits.

The `this.feedLoadingStops$` looks like this:

```
feedLoadingStops$ = this.loading$.pipe(map(v => !v), filter(v => v));
```

It inverts `false` values so they become `true`, and vice versa, so that emitted `true` value indicates that loading has stopped (remember, when `loading$` emits `false`, it indicates that loading has stopped). It also filters just `true` values so that we only get emits when it stops loading.

But, you may wander why. Why did `repeat` work for Ben and not for me? Why did I have to resubscribe only when the loading stops. It's because we both used [higher order mapping operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) after events fired by `fromEvent` to flatten the HTTP requests later on. I will certainly come to that later, but what he used was the `exhaustMap` operator, and I used `switchMap` which would *always switch* to the latest emitted item by the source and subscribe to it. When `loadMore$` is resubscribed again (using just `repeat`), it would start listening to the scroll events again, and since user would certainly continue scrolling more, `loadMore$` would start emitting once again and the `switchMap` would continue to resubscribe to the provided HTTP request all the way until user wouldn't stop scrolling. Which is really not what we want - we don't want to create multiple, exactly the same HTTP requests to fetch a single resource just because user is doing something we're responsible to solve. `exhaustMap` is different so that it does exactly the opposite to `swithcMap` - it will wait for the first emitted item to finish (basically, it will *exhaust*) until it subscribes to the next.

That was the explanation of the first event stream that will help create `filterSeed$` Observable. The other one is rather simple one. Angular provides such Observables on its own when it comes to forms. I used `this.form.valueChanges` and I was automatically subscribed to any form input element value changes. Since I only have a single `<select>` which I use to fake should I load the feed with all items or only items with text or only items with images, I would like to listen to when a user selects a different option to fire an event.

Since Angular provides this for me, you may want to create your own Observable that would emit changed form input values for you.

And finally, this is what `filterSeed$` would look like:

```
filterSeed$: Observable<FeedFilter> = defer(() => merge(
  this.loadMore$.pipe(map(() => this.form.value)),
  this.form.valueChanges
));
```

Here, I want to `merge` two streams: the one that is created by listening to the `loadMore$` events, and the other that is listening to the filter form value changes. And that is exactly what I want: I want to load new feed items only when a user has scrolled enough to the bottom or when it changed a filter. `this.form.valueChanges` already provides `FeedFilter` items, but `this.loadMore$` does not. Remember, `this.loadMore$` emits numbers which I sad I don't really care about, so I'm mapping them to `this.form.value`. This is yet again Angular specific, so you'd have to implement your own reading of the whole form input elements. Current `this.form.value` is always the same as the last emitted item from `this.form.valueChanges`.

The reason to use `defer` here is yet another Angular specific because by the time `filterSeed$` is created, `this.form` is still `undefined`, so I need to wait until subscription happens to make sure `this.form` is available. And I will subscribe to this Observable in `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook which is called upon component's view creation. You *may* not need to use `defer` here if not using Angular. Now, when everything is ready, it's time to subscribe to `this.filterSeed$` and do some data loading. Don't forget to unsubscribe when leaving component/page not to leak memory by not removing all of the event listeners created by `fromEvent`.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.subscription = this.filterSeed$.subscribe(this.feedService.filter$);
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

We now come to the second part of this answer which is `FeedService`. The `FeedService` is only a simple JS object that has some Observables and some state. I need this state in order to be able to work with multiple Observables - some might say this is not the true Rx way, but I found this to be easier for me to solve it this way.  I'm also injecting Angular's `HttpClient` (as `http` variable) to the `FeedService` which is only an Angular wrapper to XHR. You could use RxJS [ajax](https://rxjs.dev/api/ajax/ajax) static creation method instead - both should behave the same.

The `FeedService` has got three public Observables and you may have seen all of them being used in `FeedComponent`: `filter$`, `loading$` and `feed$` Observables. The later two are used by `FeedComponent` to render some stuff to the DOM, while `filter$` was used to feed it with `filterSeed$`. Basically, `filter$` is just a Subject:

```
filter$ = new Subject<FeedFilter>();
```

And since Subjects are both Observables and Observers, I could use it as an Observer, so I passed it to `subscribe` method when I subscribed to `filterSeed$` in `FeedComponent`. What this means is that `filter$` Observer will subscribe to `filterSeed$` and any call to `next` method (basically, any emission) from `filterSeed$` will pass through to the `filter$` Subject. This means that anyone else using `filter$` will get the value emitted by `filterSeed$`.

And `filter$` is used to create `feed$` Observable. Here's what it looks like:

```
feed$: Observable<FeedItem[]> = this.filter$.pipe(
  switchMap(filter => {
    if (filter !== this.filter) {
      this.filter = filter;
      this.nextPage = 1;
      this.shouldReset = true;
    }
    return this.getFeed$;
  }),
  scan((acc, value) => {
    if (this.shouldReset) {
      this.shouldReset = false;
      return value;
    }

    return acc.concat(value);
  }, [])
)
```

I'm using two operators here: `switchMap` and `scan`. I am also having some state that I keep in the class itself in variables `this.filter`, `this.nextPage` and `this.shouldReset`.

I already mentioned [higher order mapping operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/). I'm using `switchMap` here. And it is being used after events fired by `filter$` Subject which is connected through `subscribe` method with the `FeedComponent`'s `filterSeed$`. So, whenever a refresh event is fired (either by user scrolling enough or by user changing a filter in the filter form), I want to map it to `getFeed$` Observable which is responsible for creating HTTP requests. The reason to choose `switchMap` over others (over `exhaustMap` which Ben used) is that I want to make sure that I always get the result from the latest filter used by the user. I.e. if the user sent a request with one filter and changed a filter in meantime while the first request is still loading, I want to cancel that request and *switch* to another HTTP request.

Since `filter$` Subject is emitting [`FeedFilter`](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams/blob/master/src/app/models.ts#L3) objects, they are passed to `switchMap`'s callback function as `filter` parameter. This is where I'm checking if `filter` is actually the same as the filter in `FeedService` (`this.filter`). If they are not the same, it means that the filter is changed, so I need to save the new filter to the `FeedService`'s filter (`this.filter = filter;`). This also means that I have to reset page to page 1 (`this.nextPage = 1;`) and set `this.shouldReset` to `true`. Then I return `getFeed$` to which `switchMap` internally subscribes.

All of these state holding variables are later used by either `getFeed$` Observable or the next operator that comes after `switchMap`: `scan`. But, how does `getFeed$` looks like. Here's how:

```
getFeed$: Observable<FeedItem[]> = defer(() => {
    if (this.nextPage) {
      this.loadingSubject$.next(true);
      const url = appendQuery('/feed', { page: this.nextPage, feedFilter: this.filter.feedFilter });
      return this.http.get<FakeFeedResponse>(url);
    } else {
      return NEVER;
    }
  }).pipe(
    catchError(() => /* Potentially handle this.nextPage here */EMPTY),
    tap(response => {
      this.nextPage = response.nextPage;
      this.loadingSubject$.next(false);
    }),
    map(response => response.items),
    share()
  );
```

I'm again using `defer` here. This is because I'm saving some state outside of these streams, so I want values from these state variables to be read when a subscription to `getFeed$` is made, not when `getFeed$` object is created.

In the `defer`'s callback function body I'm checking if `this.nextPage` exists. The server returns `null` if there are no more items to load, so in that case, I'm returning `NEVER` which is an Observable that *never* emits. However, if there *are* items to load (when `nextPage` is a valid, truthy number), I'm returning an HTTP `get` request. `nextPage` is set to `1` by default (or is being reset to 1 in `switchMap` if filter is changed). I'm constructing `url` by [appending](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams/blob/master/src/app/feed-service/feed.service.ts#L64) `nextPage` and `feedFilter` as query string to `'/feed'` route.

Also, I'm using `loadingSubject$` to emit `true` indicating that the loading has started. `loadingSubject$` looks like this:

```
private loadingSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.loadingSubject$.asObservable();
```

It is a `BehaviorSubject` with the default value of `false`. Values emitted by this Subject are offered to `FeedComponent` through `loading$` Observable. When `FeedComponent` first subscribes to `loading$` Observable, it will get `false` immediately.

The `this.http.get<FakeFeedResponse>(url)` request returned to `defer` is using Angular XHR wrapper. I'm injecting `http` to `FeedService`, but you should be able to use RxJS's `ajax` as I already mentioned. It emits objects of [FakeFeedResponse](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams/blob/master/src/app/models.ts#L7) type.

After this Observable is constructed using `defer`, I want to do some more stuff when it emits. First thing is to handle errors using `catchError`. If an error happens, I want to return an `EMPTY` Observable which just completes without emitting any item. I added comment here so that you may add some more error handling or handle (re)setting of `nextPage` or something.

After that, I'm saving `nextPage` from the `response` in `tap` and also emitting `false` to `loadingSubject$` indicating that the loading has stopped. After `tap`, I'm using `map` to extract `items` from the `response`.

And then I'm `share`ing it. This is actually not really needed in my case. Why? Because there is only one subscriber to `getFeed$` (which is `switchMap`) so there's really no need to `share` it across multiple subscribers, but it can stay here *if* it would ever need - actually, if there would ever exist another subscriber. I added it because Ben added it as well, but he has more than one subscriber to his `getFeed$` Observable.

And that's all about `getFeed$` which is being returned to `switchMap` in its callback method. In `feed$` Observable, after `switchMap`, I'm using `scan`. Actually, `scan` is here just so that Angular's `async` pipe could receive already loaded items by concatenating new values to an already loaded ones (`acc.concat(value)`). I'm using `this.shouldReset` flag here so that I don't use `concat` when the filter is changed. If you would not use Angular, you would probably subscribe yourself to `feed$` Observable and you would probably handle this case yourself instead of `scan`, so you wouldn't probably need to have `scan` here.

After all, I'm using Angular Interceptor feature to [fake](https://github.com/jakovljevic-mladen/ng-pagination-rx-streams/blob/master/src/app/interceptor.ts) all of the server responses. Please take a look how.

And that's it. I'm really sorry for the very long answer, if you have questions, please open an Issue on GitHub. I really hope that this answer might help you shape your solution, which I didn't really look at, I'm sorry.

If you'd like to try this example, you can clone the project, run `npm install` and then `ng serve` which will compile the whole project and run a dev server so you can try this project on your own.